# org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception java.io.IOException: Invalid argument

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I am having the following error when starting up the tomcat server 7 in Eclipse Mars, but the same tomcat server reconfigured in Eclipse Luna is started fine.

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception java.io.IOException: Invalid argument  at 
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)    at 
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)    at 
java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)   at 
java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)   at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:173)   at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:139)     at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:80)   at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:199)  at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:398)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?